# ubuntu acts as if shift key is being pressed

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse

so my ubuntu is going crazy.

it just acts as if shift is always pressed sometimes and with caps lock going insane when it wants as well: the mouse also seems weird; every time i click in anything it opens a new browser window: this is driving me insane; is there a fix? 
(It just went back to normal, I literally didn't do a thing, now I can write properly.) I was using librecalc and suddenly it started selecting cells and everytime I clicked in anything it selected a cell.

Will i just need to go back to windows again? I prefer ubuntu but this is unbearable.

[System settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr8Le.png)

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/934924/edit) your question and supply us with more information like Ubuntu version you are running?  What type of hardware are you running this on?  Laptop?  Desktop?  Any more information that you can give us would be greatly appreciated because as your question is written does not give us enough detail to help you.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot. Attached a link of my system settings (screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this type of thing can be caused by low battery power in keyboard/mouse HID devices  (bluetooth or RF).
They send corrupted data stream to the host, which then causes the rather random behaviour you experience.
It can seem intermittent, so worth checking batteries. 
There can be other causes but since this one has an easy diagnostic it can be checked easily.